# Deriving the difference between compound interest and simple interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

What is the derivation for the formula that gives the difference between compound interest and simple interest after three years: $P\left(\frac R{100}\right)^2 \left(\frac R{100} + 3\right)$? It is the formula for C.I - S.I for 3 years which I read in many different places but I'm not able to figure out how it is derived.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing we do, let's kill all the percentages. Calculations like this are much easier when interest rates are given as pure numbers, for example $0.02$ instead of $2$%.

So if you start with principal $P$ and leave it invested at a rate $r$ 
(where $r = \frac R{100}$) for three years at simple interest, you end up
with $P(1 + 3r)$ at the end.

But if you earn compound interest, the amount at the end is $P(1 + r)^3$.

Now take the difference in the outcomes:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
 P(1 + r)^3 - P(1 + 3r)
  &=& P(1 + 3r + 3r^2 + r^3) - P(1 + 3r) \\
  &=& P(3r^2 + r^3) \\
  &=& P(3 + r)r^2.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Now that we know the answer, we can put it back in terms of percentages
if we must:

$$P(3 + r)r^2 = P \left(3 + \frac{R}{100}\right) \left(\frac{R}{100}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

The formula for simple interest is

\begin{align*}
A = P \bigg(1 +\dfrac{n R}{100}\bigg)\tag{1}
\quad\text{where}&\\
&\text{A = final amount after interest}\\
&\text{P = original principal}\\
&\text{n = number of cycles for interest rate}\\
&\text{R = annual interest rate}\\
\text{but compound interest is}&\\
&A=P\bigg(1+\frac{R}{100}\bigg)^{\Large{n}}\\ \tag{2}
\text{ compounding  once/year}&\\
\text{or}&\\
&A = \space P\bigg(1+\dfrac{R}{100n}\bigg)^{\Large{nt}}\\ 
&\text{n is the number of payments per year}\\
&\text{t = number of years}
\end{align*}

I believe what you want is the difference between either of $\quad(2)\space$ minus $\space(1)$